# Problems about Polymorphisms and Threading in C++

Tags: c++

in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class bc
{
public:
    virtual void call() const = 0;
};

class dc1 : public bc
{
public:
    void call() const override
    {
        clog << "D1 called." << '\n';
    }
};

class dc2 : public bc
{
public:
    void call() const override
    {
        clog << "D2 called." << '\n';
    }
};

class dc_list : public bc
{
public:
    vector<shared_ptr<bc>> list;

    void call() const override
    {
        for (auto &item : list)
            item -> call();
    }
};

class testTool
{
public:
    void render(const bc& world) const
    {
        vector<thread> vt;
        vt.emplace_back(&testTool::renderLine, this, world);
        vt.emplace_back(&testTool::renderLine, this, world);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            vt[i].join();
    }

    void renderLine(const bc& world) const
    {
        world.call(); // do something reclusive
    }
};

void test()
{
    dc_list world;
    world.list.push_back(make_shared<dc1>());
    world.list.push_back(make_shared<dc1>());
    world.list.push_back(make_shared<dc2>());
    world.list.push_back(make_shared<dc2>());

    testTool t;
    t.render(world);
}
```

when invoking `test()`, it failed to compile with lots of errors which seem to say that it was trying to instantize an abstract class.

here comes a part of the log:

```
C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tuple:165:13: error: cannot declare field 'std::_Head_base<2, bc, false>::_M_head_impl' to be of abstract type 'bc'
       _Head _M_head_impl;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\26257\Desktop\CodeTestField\launcher.cpp:7:
C:\Users\26257\Desktop\CodeTestField\dynamic.h:7:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'bc':
 class bc
       ^~
C:\Users\26257\Desktop\CodeTestField\dynamic.h:10:18: note:     'virtual void bc::call() const'
     virtual void call() const = 0;
```

could anyone tell me why?

I tried to replace the param to `render(const bc& world)` with `const dc_list& world` and it work perfectly. Yet I am still confused about the reason why `bc&` can't work.

new `render()` func:

```
void render(const dc_list& world) const
{
   ...(same as before)...
}
```

by the way, it can also work if I do not use threads.

still can't get it why the original code can't run. it make no sense to me.